# Understanding the construction of an uncomputable function

Tags: computability, turing-machines, undecidability

The following is from Arora and Barak's "Computational Complexity." I think one does not have to read the second paragraph of the proof to answer this question.

> **Theorem 1.10** There exists a function $\operatorname{UC}:\{0,1\}^*\to\{0,1\}$ that is not computable by any TM (turing machine).
>
> Proof: The function $\operatorname{UC}$ is defined as follows: For every $\alpha\in\{0,1\}^*$, if $M_\alpha(\alpha)=1$, then $\operatorname{UC}(\alpha)=0$; otherwise (if $M_\alpha(\alpha)$ outputs a different value or enters an infinite loop), $\operatorname{UC}(\alpha)=1$.
>
> Suppose for the sake of contradiction that $\operatorname{UC}$ is computable and hence there exists a TM $M$ such that $M(\alpha)=\operatorname{UC}(\alpha)$ for every $\alpha\in\{0,1\}^*$. Then, in particular, $M(\lfloor M\rfloor) = \operatorname{UC}(\lfloor M\rfloor)$. But this is impossible: By the definition of $\operatorname{UC}$,
> \begin{equation}
> \operatorname{UC}(\lfloor M\rfloor)=1 \Leftrightarrow M(\lfloor M\rfloor)\neq 1
> \end{equation}

My question is, how can one be sure that $\operatorname{UC}$ is well-defined? What if the result of $M_\alpha(\alpha)$ is mathematically undetermined (i.e., Both $M_\alpha(\alpha)=1$ and its negation are not provable from the axioms)?

---

**Notations.** $\{0,1\}^*$ is the set of all strings composed of $0$ and $1$. $M_\alpha$ is the turing machine represented by the string $\alpha$. $\lfloor M\rfloor$ is a string representing the turing machine $M$.

Comment: The assumption here is that even if something is unprovable, it can still be either true or false.

Comment: $\mathsf{UC}$ is well-defined by excluded middle: either $M_\alpha(\alpha) = 1$ or not. The whole thing has nothing to do with provability, nor is the assumption "even if something is unprovable it can still be true or false" present anywhere (and it's a really strange "assumption" to make in the first place).

Comment: @PeterShor: it is not an assumption that statements are either true or false, even when unprovable. That's just the law of excluded middle. Or are you talking about intuitionistic mathematics?

Comment: @Andrej Bauer: The law of the excluded middle **is** an assumption.

Comment: @PeterShor: Thank you for making your position clear. It is of course a valid possibility, namely making every mathematical statement you ever utter contingent on all the laws of logic. I am not sure this is the best way to explain the current question, however.

Comment: @AndrejBauer Conceptually, how is uncomputable function related to Godel's true (but unprovable) statements from first Incompleteness Theorem?

Comment: @Ajax: I do not understand your question.

Comment: @AndrejBauer Is "uncomputability" behind Incompleteness?

Comment: @Ajax: If you would like to ask a precise, I recommend you do it on math.stackexchange.com. These comments cannot serve that purpose.

Comment: The *existence* of uncomputable functions follows trivially from cardinality arguments (computable functions are a countable set). The *interesting* result is that there are Recursively Enumerable yet undecidable languages.

Comment: @Andrej Bauer: one way I expressed my comment the way I did is that I didn't want to tell the OP that he was completely wrong when there are (intuitionist) mathematicians who reason the same way that he intuitively did.

Comment: @PeterShor:  You must be thinking of intuitionistic explanations of truth that equate truth with provability (which I disagree with when I pretend to be an intuitionist). It would be helpful if the OP gave some feeback. On the other hand, I don't think it's worth dwelling on this particular question any longer.

Answer (score 1):

The question is not research-level but since some of the comments following it may be confusing, allow me to explain precisely how functions are defined by cases.

Suppose we would like to define a function $f : A \to B$ by cases, like this:
$$
f(x) =
\begin{cases}
e_1(x) & \text{if $\phi(x)$},\\
e_2(x) & \text{if $\psi(x)$},
\end{cases}
$$
where expressions $e_1(x)$ and $e_2(x)$may depend on $x$.
When is this a valid definition? In set theory (and many other kinds of foundations) a function is the same thing as a functional relation, so let us recall what that means.

**Definition:** A relation $R \subseteq A \times B$ is *functional* when for every $x \in A$ there exists exactly one $y \in B$ such that $(x, y) \in R$. The function $f_R : A \to B$ determined by such a functional relation maps $x \in A$ to the (unique) $y \in B$ for which $(x,y) \in R$.

The above definition by cases can be written in terms of functional relations, as follows. Define $R \subseteq A \times B$ by
$$R = \{(x,y) \in A \times B \mid (\phi(x) \Rightarrow y = e_1) \land (\psi(x) \Rightarrow y = e_2) \}.
$$
The $f$ defined by cases is then precisely $f_R$. But the question is, what condition must $\phi(x)$ and $\psi(x)$ satisfy in order for $R$ to be functional? A little exercise in logic shows that two conditions must be met:

1. **Overlap:** for all $x \in A$, if $\phi(x)$ and $\psi(x)$ then $e_1 = e_2$.
2. **Cover:** for all $x \in A$, $\phi(x)$ or $\psi(x)$.

Indeed, agreement on overlap guarantees that $R$ is single-valued, and the cover condition that it is total.

Now we look at the definition given by the OP:

$$
\mathrm{UC}(\alpha) =
\begin{cases}
0 & \text{if $M_\alpha(\alpha)$ is defined and $M_\alpha(\alpha) = 1$}\\
1 & \text{if $M_\alpha(\alpha)$ is not defined or $M_\alpha(\alpha) \neq 1$}
\end{cases}
$$
So in this case $\phi(x)$ is “$M_\alpha(\alpha)$ is defined and $M_\alpha(\alpha) = 1$”
and
$\psi(x)$ is $\neg \phi(x)$.
Clearly, the overlap condition is satisfied because there is no $\alpha$ satisfying both $\phi(\alpha)$ and $\neg \phi(\alpha)$.
The cover condition holds because $\phi(\alpha) \lor \neg \phi(\alpha)$ is true by the law of excluded middle (this would be problematic if we worked in intuitionistic logic, where excluded middle is not accepted).
In conclusion, $\mathrm{UC}$ is well defined.